# select key-value pairs from json as rows in Snowflake

Tags: json, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

Assume I have the following JSON:

```
{
  "CURRENCY_CODE": "INR",
  "CURRENCY_NAME": "Indian Rupee",
  "ID_CURRENCY": 8,
  "ISO_CODE": 4217
}
```

I want to query it in Snowflake so I get the following output:

| Key | Value |
| --- | --- |
| CURRENCY_CODE | INR |
| CURRENCY_NAME | Indian Rupee |
| ID_CURRENCY | 8 |
| ISO_CODE | 4217 |

I expect something like:

```
select d.key, d.value
from table('Here goes json') d
```

Does Snowflake have any function to achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is possible to pass the argument directly into [FLATTEN](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/functions/flatten.html):

```
SELECT f.*
FROM TABLE(FLATTEN(INPUT => PARSE_JSON('<here goes json>'))) f;
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `LATERAL FLATTEN()` in your FROM clause to achieve this.

As an example:

```
SELECT fdt.KEY, fdt.VALUE
FROM VALUES('{
  "CURRENCY_CODE": "INR",
  "CURRENCY_NAME": "Indian Rupee",
  "ID_CURRENCY": 8,
  "ISO_CODE": 4217
}') dt
,lateral flatten( input => parse_json(column1) ) fdt;
```

| KEY | VALUE |
| --- | --- |
| CURRENCY_CODE | INR |
| CURRENCY_NAME | Indian Rupee |
| ID_CURRENCY | 8 |
| ISO_CODE | 4217 |